how do I separate the positive and negative values in one column into separate columns using DAX?
I want to separate the values in one column into separate columns, so that the negative values will be on one column and the positive in one column.
See sample dataset below



Column A
Amount




revenue
2300


expenses
-1990


revenue
100


revenue
1093


expenses
-299



I want to separate the values in one column into separate columns, so that the negative values will be on one column and the positive in one column.

You could add a new column to look at Amount and if it is positive, return the positive value, otherwise be blank. And then do the same for if it is a negative value in a second column. There's more information about IF statements here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/if-function-dax
For example (if your table was called Table1):
PositiveAmount = IF('Table1'[Amount] >= 0, 'Table1'[Amount], Blank())

NegativeAmount = IF('Table1'[Amount] < 0, 'Table1'[Amount], Blank())


thanks very much. it solved my questions. i appreciate

@BashiruOtokiti I'm glad it worked. If the question has been successfully answered, it's normal to click the check mark next to the answer to accept it
